# Best way to cut up some shell output?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

Below is the output from the command `cvt 1280 760`. I need to extract everything after the second `"` to the end of of the line to use in the next line of my shell script. What's the nicest way of doing that?

```
# 1280x760 59.91 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.33 kHz; pclk: 78.75 MHz
Modeline "1280x760_60.00"   78.75  1280 1344 1472 1664  760 763 773 790 -hsync +vsync
```

Comment: did you want to get the first line?

Comment: Nope, just everything starting 78.75 (won't always be 78.75) on the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sed.

```
sed -n 's/^[^"]*"[^"]*"[[:blank:]]*//p' file
```

or grep

```
grep -oP '^[^"]*"[^"]*"\s*\K.*' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (with input on `stdin`):

```
grep \" | cut -d\" -f3-
```

- `grep \" |` -- only lines with `"`
- `-d\"` -- `"` is your delimeter
- `-f3-` -- you want the 3rd field and everything after it

---

For your `file`:

```
<file grep \" | cut -d\" -f3-
```

It outputs:

```
  78.75  1280 1344 1472 1664  760 763 773 790 -hsync +vsync
```

Comment: I tried this one like this  cvt 1280 760 | cut -d\" -f3-
but it just returned the full output?

Comment: For your input, in gives me '  78.75  1280 1344 1472 1664  760 763 773 790 -hsync +vsync', i.e.--everything after the second `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` would likely work:

```
awk -F'"[ ]+' '{print $2}' file
```

Using `-F` +  `"(one or more spaces)` acts as the field separator.

Answer (score 0):

with bash:

```
while IFS='"' read field1 field2 rest; do
    # do something with "$rest"
    echo "$rest"; 
done < <( cvt 1280 760 )
```

The last line is a redirection from a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bash Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='Modeline "1280x760_60.00"   78.75  1280 1344 1472 1664  760 763 773 790 -hsync +vsync'
pat='[^"]*"[^"]*"(.*)'
[[ $s =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
   78.75  1280 1344 1472 1664  760 763 773 790 -hsync +vsync
```